# Find highest growth using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe named growth with 4 columns.

```
State Name  Average Fare ($)_x  Average Fare ($)_y  Average Fare ($)
0   AK  599.372368  577.790640  585.944324
1   AL  548.825867  545.144447  555.939466
2   AR  496.033146  511.867026  513.761296
3   AZ  324.641818  396.895324  389.545267
4   CA  368.937971  376.723839  366.918761
5   CO  502.611572  537.206439  531.191893
6   CT  394.105453  388.772428  370.904182
7   DC  390.872738  382.326510  392.394165
8   FL  324.941100  329.728524  337.249248
9   GA  485.335737  480.606365  489.574241
10  HI  326.084793  335.547369  298.709998
11  IA  428.151682  445.625840  462.614195
12  ID  482.092567  475.822275  491.714945
13  IL  329.449503  349.938794  346.022226
14  IN  391.627917  418.945137  412.242053
15  KS  452.312058  490.024059  420.182836
```

The last three columns are the average fare of each year of each state. 
2nd,3rd,4th column being year 2017,2018,2019 respectively.
I wanted to find out that which state has highest growth in fare since 2017.

I tried with this code of mine and it gives some output that I cant really understand.
 I just need to find the state that has highest fare growth since 2017.

my code:

```
growth[['Average Fare ($)_x','Average Fare ($)_y','Average Fare ($)']].pct_change()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about variation prices the total growth/decrease in fare will be the variation from 2017 to your last available data (2019). Therefore you can compute this ratio and then just get the `max()` to find the row with the most growth.

```
growth['variation_fare'] =  growth['Average Fare ($)'] / growth['Average Fare ($)_x']
growth = growth.sort_values(['variation_fare'],ascending=False)
print(growth.head(1))
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'State':['AK','AL','AR','AZ','CA'],'2017':[100,200,300,400,500],'2018':[120,242,324,457,592],'2019':[220,393,484,593,582]}
growth = pd.DataFrame(a)
growth['2018-2017 variation'] = (growth['2018'] / growth['2017']) - 1
growth['2019-2018 variation'] = (growth['2019'] / growth['2018']) - 1
growth['total variation'] = (growth['2019'] / growth['2017']) - 1
growth = growth.sort_values(['total variation'],ascending=False)
print(growth.head(5)) #Showing top 5
```

Output:

```
  State  2017  2018  2019  2018-2017 variation  2019-2018 variation  total variation
0    AK   100   120   220               0.2000             0.833333         1.200000
1    AL   200   242   393               0.2100             0.623967         0.965000
2    AR   300   324   484               0.0800             0.493827         0.613333
3    AZ   400   457   593               0.1425             0.297593         0.482500
4    CA   500   592   582               0.1840            -0.016892         0.164000
```

Comment: Why din you use the year 2018?

Comment: Because if you want to find the one with the highest growth from 2017, what counts is the variation between initial value and end value. If 2017 is 100, 2018 is 1000 and 2019 is 100 again, how much would you say the growth has been from 2017? 0. Because you are measuring the overall variation, not the year-ly variation

Comment: and how do you calculate yearly variation?

Comment: The same way, computing the ratio between the values. There you have the full example. You can also see that `(1+2018-2017 variation)*(1+2019-2018 variation) = total variation` it works the same as compound interest rates, or inflation rates.

Answer (score 3):

```
growth[['Average Fare ($)_x','Average Fare ($)_y','Average Fare ($)']].pct_change(axis='columns')
```

This should give you the percentage change between each year.

```
growth['variation_percentage'] = growth[['Average Fare ($)_x','Average Fare ($)_y','Average Fare ($)']].pct_change(axis='columns').sum(axis=1)
```

This should give you the cumulative percentage change.

Comment: Best method. But chose other one as the answer because of the efforts involved

Comment: Always answer the right answer because it helps other people who have the same question. But it's okay if you think that answer is valid too.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can you this

```
df.set_index('State_name').pct_change(periods  = 1, axis='columns').idxmax()
```

Change the `periods` value to 2 if you want to calculate the difference between first year & the 3rd year.

**output**

```
Average_fare_x    NaN
Average_fare_y     AZ #state with max change between 1st & 2nd year
Average_fare       WV #state with max change between 2nd & 3rd year
```

Comment: I am basically trying to see the fare growth from 2017 to 2019. so I think all three years are accountable in the calculation, right?

Comment: No, if you want the overall growth from 2017 to 2019, you do not need 2018. You only need to calculate the variation between first value and last value.

Comment: @CeliusStingher is correct. you just need you do not need 2018. Then you just have to change the periods  to 2 in the code that I have put.

Comment: Simple and effective method. But chose other one as the answer because of the efforts involved

Comment: Understood. You can up-vote the answer if it helped (you can up-vote the accepted answer too).